# Combining is in and where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, combinations, where-clause

How can I create new column based on the odd even flag in Pandas

This is my data:

```
id   Flag
001   1
002   2
003   3
004   4
```

I would like to have this output if flag is even number then female, if flag is odd number then male:

```
id   Flag   Gender
001   1     Male
002   2     Female
003   3     Male
004   4     Female
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with modulo `2` for check even and odd numbers:

```
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['Flag'] % 2,'Male','Female')
print (df)
   id  Flag  Gender
0   1     1    Male
1   2     2  Female
2   3     3    Male
3   4     4  Female
```

Answer (score 0):

try apply

```
 Id =['001','002','003','004']
 Flag=[1,2,3,4]  
 df=pd.DataFrame({'id':Id,'flag':Flag})

 df['gender']=df['flag'].apply(lambda x: 'Male' if x%2 else 'Female')
```

output:

```
 id  flag  gender
 0  001     1    Male
 1  002     2  Female
 2  003     3    Male
 3  004     4  Female
```